# Javascript do / while loop displays unexpected result

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

Can someone help me understand why the problem below happens on the below excersise?

The loops should count up and down in increments of 5 along with a string of text.
The three loops all work except that the do / while loop does not include the text string with the final number. It just says '50' rather than 'The number 50'.

```
for (x=1; x<50; x+=5) {
    console.log("The number " + x);
}

var y = 50
while (y>1) {
    console.log("The number " + y);
    y-=5;
}

var z = 0;
do {
    console.log("The number " + z);
    z+=5;
}

while(z<50);
```

Comment: Yeah, this should never print "50" by itself. There must be something we're not seeing.

Comment: `do..while` loop should not reach `50` ; the condition at `while` is `z<50`

Comment: it will stop at 45 because of the condition. Make it z <= 50 if you want it like that

Answer (score 1):

### None of them are inclusive; they all fail to output the last number.

**Important: this error has nothing to do with using `do-while` vs. `while` or `for`. The reason you did not notice it for the others is that the last value of one variable is overlapping with the first of the next**

If you log which variable is actually being printed as well, you will see this.

```
console.log('x: ');
for (x=1; x<50; x+=5) {
    console.log("The number x " + x);
}

console.log('y: ');
var y = 50
while (y>1) {
    console.log("The number y " + y);
    y-=5;
}

console.log('z: ');
var z = 0;
do {
    console.log("The number z " + z);
    z+=5;
}

while(z<50);
```

The reason why you are not printing the last number is that you are incrementing/decrementing *after* printing.

Consider the following loop:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < 5){
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

When `i` is 4, here's what happens:

1. log `i` (4)
2. increment `i` (now 5)
3. is `i < 5`? **false**
4. <exit loop>

As you can see, `i` *reaches* the last number, but doesn't get printed once it does. A simple fix for this problem is to switch the `<` for a `<=` to make the loop inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Of course "The number 50" should not be displayed in your case:

```
...
console.log("The number " + z) // z == 45
z+=5 // z == 50
}
while (z<50); // no, exit from cycle
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`do-while` Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.1) is defined as (emphasis mine):

> The production `do` *Statement* `while` `(` *Expression* `);` is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *V* = empty.
> 2. Let *iterating* be true.
> 3. Repeat, while *iterating* is true
>
>    1. Let *stmt* be the result of evaluating *Statement*.
>    2. If *stmt*.value is not empty, let V = *stmt*.value.
>    3. If *stmt*.type is not continue || *stmt*.target is not in the current label set, then
>
>       1. If *stmt*.type is break and *stmt*.target is in the current label set, return (normal, *V*, empty).
>       2. If *stmt* is an abrupt completion, return stmt.
>    4. Let *exprRef* be the result of evaluating *Expression*.
>    5. If ToBoolean(GetValue(*exprRef*)) is false, set *iterating* to false.
> 4. **Return (normal, *V*, empty);**

Therefore, the evaluation of the `do-while` statement returns *V*, the value of the last evaluated statement inside it.

In this case, it's 50. If you run the code in the console, the console will display the value returned by the code, so you will see 50.

If you run it on a page, you won't see that 50.